# Validation is always one key press behind

Tags: angular, validation, angular-directive

I have written a custom date validator directive that allows me to compare two date input fields (granted, this problem should exist for any data type).  The validator has two Inputs one of which is the target control to compare to.

Everything works except for the fact that validation is always one key press behind when the user is updating the "targetDate" control.  The "sourceDate" control behaves as expected.  For example, the user enters a date, say 2/7/2018, into the sourceDate control.  A validation message will appear telling the user that the sourceDate must be less than or equal to the targetDate.  User updates the targetDate control to a date greater than sourceDate, say 2/8/2018, but the validation error message on sourceDate remains.  The user types one more number making the target date entry display 2/8/20188 and the validation message disappears.  User hits backspace changing the target date back to 2/8/2018 and the validation message remains hidden.  So it appears that the validation check is always a key press behind for the targetDate control.  Again, the sourceDate control doesn't behave like this.

Here is an example of the code:

**template form:**

```
<my-date-picker name="sourceDate"
                myDateComparerValidator="<=" [compareTo]="targetDate"
                [(ngModel)]="sourceDate"
                #sourceDate="ngModel">
</my-date-picker>
<my-validate-message *ngIf="sourceDate.errors?.ltet"
                     message="Source Date must be Less Than or Equal To Target Date">
</my-validate-message>    

<my-date-picker name="targetDate"
                [(ngModel)]="targetDate"
                #targetDate="ngModel">
</my-date-picker>
```

**validator directive:**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDateComparerValidator]',
    providers: [
        {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, multi: true, useExisting: DateComparerValidatorDirective}
    ]
})
export class DateComparerValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('myDateComparerValidator')
    operator: string;

    @Input('compareTo')
    compareTo: NgModel;

    validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        const errors: ValidationErrors = {};

        const value: Date = new Date(c.value);
        const compareTo: Date = this.compareTo.model;

        // comparison logic based on operator input //

        return errors;
}
```

Is this not possible?  Am I forced to wrap these controls into a form-group validation (which I'm trying to avoid for reasons).

Comment: just a random dude that doesn't know angular passing by, but shouldn't you add the same validator to targetDate too?

Comment: What I have shown is just an example.  In the actual application there are several date fields.  The "targetDate" field would actually have a validator pointing to another date field other than "sourceDate".  And you can't have the same validator directive twice on the same control (at least, I don't think you can).

Comment: Only if a input has a validator, Angular check the validator if change the field, so you must add another validator to targetDate (or change the actual validator to accept an attribute)